# Ant prompt user for a git branch

Tags: deployment, ant

I'm using Ant as a deployment tool to our staging server, now I would like to prompt the user who's deploying what branch he would like to deploy. Is there a way in Ant to display the branches and let the user pick one by entering a number? Something like you see in a lot of CLI wizards.

```
What branch would you like to deploy (default: master)
 [0] master
 [1] develop
 [2] feature/reporting
 [3] feature/corerefactor
```

It this possible with Ant?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ant Input task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)

```
<input
  message="What branch would you like to deploy?"
  validargs="0,1,2,3"
  defaultvalue="0"
  addproperty="branch.choice"
/>
```

To make it similar to your the sample in your question, `echo` the choices first.

You can add `taskname="blah"` to both `input` and `echo` tasks to make them look consistent to the user.